# Using bitrate in conversion of a set of images to a video changes the length of the video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, image-conversion

I have ffmpeg version n5.0.1-3-gb655beb025 and I am trying to convert a set of 120 PNGs to an AVI file with 60 frames/sec. When I do that with:

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 60 -i Frame-%%05d.png MyVideoLQ.avi
```

it creates the video with correct length (2.00 sec.), but the quality is poor (bitrate is 200kbps). So, I tried to fix the problem via bitrate and buffer:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Frame-%%05d.png -b:v 4096k -maxrate:v 4096k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize 4096k -r 60 MyVideoHQ.avi
```

The result has a good quality, but the video has 4.8 seconds now.

1. Is it a bug, or did I misunderstand the used options?
2. How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Well, there is a hack to do that. I have noticed that the output is always 2.4 times longer than it should be. So, I may post-process the video, e.g. with melt, and use the appropriate replay speed to generate a video that has the correct length. But obviously, that would be an ad-hoc solution, which may very well stop to work in the next version of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `-r 60` **before** the `-i`:

`ffmpeg.exe -r 60 -i Frame-%%05d.png -b:v 4096k -maxrate:v 4096k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize 4096k MyVideoHQ.avi`

---

When the `-r 60` is before the `-i`, the framerate applies the input.
When the `-r 60` is before after the `-i`, the framerate applies the output.

When we have sequence of images as input, the input framerate is assumed to be 25fps (FFmpeg default).
When the input is 25fps, and the output is required to be 60fps FFmpeg applies framerate conversion (from 25fps to 60fps) by duplicating frames.

The ratio `60/25` = `2.4`

For that reason the output is always 2.4 times longer.

---

For getting better quality with less arguments, we may select video codec and `crf` setting.

Example:

`ffmpeg.exe -r 60 -i Frame-%%05d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 MyVideoHQ.avi`

Lower `crf` applies higher quality and larger file size.

Comment: Thank you very much for both, the solution and the explanation. Works as stated. :)